# List except and union two list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have two list.
I need remove items from the first list are not in the second list and add the other elements of the first.

```
foreach (var product in item.Products)
{
    item.Products.Remove(product);
}

var newProducts = _catalogService.GetProductBaseItems(x => model.Products.Contains(x.Id))
                  .ToList();

foreach (var product in newProducts)
{
    item.Products.Add(product);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you; imagine you have `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` and `[1, 2, 4, 5]`. So you have to remove both `3` from the 1st list: `[1, 2, 2, 4]`, and what should I add then? What is the expected outcoume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Except` to find all which are in the first but not in the second. But since your `Product` class might not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` by comparing the ID's you either have to do it, create a custom `IEqualityComparer<Product>` or use following approach:

```
IEnumerable<int> idsInFirstNotSecond = item.Products
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .Except(newProducts.Select(x => x.Id));
var productsInFirstNotSecond = from p in item.Products
                               join id in idsInFirstNotSecond 
                               on p.Id equals id
                               select p;
List<Product> completeListOfOldAndNew =  productsInFirstNotSecond
    .Concat(newProducts)
    .ToList()
```